# Show that the heisenberg group is nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, nilpotence

This time I want to show that $H(R)$ ( the heisenberg group attached to a conmutative ring $R$ is nilpotent). But I dont know how to proceed, I was thinking in first serch the normal subgroups if the Heisenberg group and then try to figure out the quotient group of that, from there get the centre, etc, but I dont think it would be a good idea (In fact I thought to use Gap, but I dont know how to ask this questions in Sage), Is there a better way to do this? Thanks a lot.

For me

$H(R) = \left \{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & c \\ 0 & 1 & b \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}: \ \ a,b,c \in R \right \}$

For a conmutative ring $R$

Comment: What's your definition of $H(R)$?

Comment: Let me post it :)

Comment: Just compute commutator of two such guys; the result will show that this commutator is in the center of the group.

Comment: Ok, but with that I am proving that the group is nilpotent?

Comment: Yes, if the commutator subgroup is in the center, this means the group is actually stage 2 nilpotent, since all subsequent commutators will be trivial (commutators of the center with anything are trivial, this is the definition of the center)

Comment: Ok then why in the answer, I have to guess the conmutator of three matrices?

Comment: You would not need that actually, once you've done two :)

Comment: Ok then just the conmutator of two of this matrices, and then this is done right?

Comment: Once it is in the center, yes, since then commutator of three will be obvious

Comment: Ok then I have to check it is in the cerntre?

Comment: Yes - more precisely the result should show you at the same time what the center is: once you know commutator $[X,Y]$ of arbitrary two elements of the group, then in particular you will know those $C$ with $[C,Y]=1$ for all $Y$, and the center is made precisely of such $C$.

Comment: Ok, let me try it, if I have some troubles Can I ask for help?, and another thing, the conmutator is $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ rght?

Comment: Yes. And for inverses you can use the thing I mentioned in the comment to the answer.

Comment: I have done the computation in mathematica :), and it gives me the following $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & af-cd \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: You can not enter such group in GAP in principle. What you can do in GAP is to play with matrices with some particular rational values of $a$, $b$, $c$ - compute their commutators and spot some pattern. That may give you an extra clue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, I am new in GAP and I didt know that :) thanks

Comment: I think what prevents you from seeing the answer (which is by now straightforward) is that you are relying on software too much. Don't wait that it will figure out anything for you, it can only give you enough evidence to figure out things by yourself. And by now it gave more than enough of that.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** The Heisenberg group $H(R)$ is the subgroup
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \ast & \ast \\ 0 & 1 & \ast \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
of $\mathrm{GL}_3(R)$.

You should start by just taking the commutator of two such elements and seeing what it looks like.  It should be pretty easy to identify $[H(R), H(R)]$ and then take a guess at what $[H(R), [H(R), H(R)]]$ is.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you post the conmutator explicity please?

Comment: It is very easy to compute once you know the inverses. And the latter are easy to find since your matrices are of the form $1+x$ with $x^3=0$.

Comment: I'm not actually going to post the commutator.  I've laid out a very walkable path for you, but I'm not giving you a piggy back ride ;)

If you're having trouble with some part of the computation you should post what work you've already done and indicate where it is that you're stuck.  I'd be happy to help you get unstuck.