# Showing a Group of Matrices is Nilpotent

Tags: group-theory

I'm working on a homework question which states:

> Show that the real Heisenberg group 
>       H=  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & a & c\\ 0 & 1 & b\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} 
>   for a,b,c $\in \mathbb{R}$ is nilpotent.

I've shown the center of $H$ to be matrices of the form
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & c\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}

and I am now trying to calculate the center, $Z_2(H/Z(H))$, for the ascending central series. I think the center is supposed to be all of $H/Z(H)$, so I am trying to show these cosets are abelian, and I think that is where my issue is. For two cosets, $hZ(H)$ and $gZ(H)$, $(g,h \in H)$ I am confused what this looks like and how to show they commute.

Any help on this is appreciated. I know there are other ways to do this, but I would like to use the ascending central series since that is the way I am learning it. Thanks!

In response to the duplicate, I understand this is the same question, but I think my approach is different. Looking at the other question, they are using a method I am unfamiliar with. I think I can show that the cosets are abelian, but am unsure how to proceed from there. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192937/show-that-the-heisenberg-group-is-nilpotent).

Comment: All strictly triangular matrices are nilpotent.

Comment: @Shogun: (i) You are confusing "nilpotent" in the sense of ring theory and "nilpotent" in the sense of group theory. (ii) Unitriangular matrices (upper triangular matrices with $1$s in the diagonal) are not strictly triangular.

Comment: To show that $hZ(H)$ commutes with $gZ(H)$, show that $hg$ and $gh$ differ by an element of $Z(H)$ (as $(hZ(H))(gZ(H)) = (gZ(H))(hZ(H))$ if and only if $ghZ(H) = hgZ(H)$ if and only if $(gh)(hg)^{-1}\in Z(H)$ ).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you! This is exactly what I needed as help!